# Find root of non-continuous function using a numerical method

Tags: numerical-methods

> Given the formula ([source](http://www.hughchou.org/calc/formula.html))
>   $$ M = P \times \frac{J}{1 - (1 + J)^{-N}}$$
>   Assume $P$ and $J$ remain constant. I want to be able to find $N$ for given $M.$

Could you please give an example of a numeric method (like secant to solve the same)? [My] problem is how to find initial 2 values for the secant formula.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, we're given, $M,P,J$ and we're trying to find $N.$

Well, we have
$$ 1 - (1+J)^{-N} = \frac{PJ}{M} \\
 (1+J)^{-N} = 1 - \frac{PJ}{M} $$
Take $\log$ both sides:
$$ -N \log{(1+J)} = \log{(1 - \frac{PJ}{M})} \\
N = - \frac{\log{(1 - \frac{PJ}{M})}}{\log{(1+J)}}
$$
Since $M, P, J$ are given, we can very well compute the RHS, and hence compute $N.$

Did I mis-understood your question?

Comment: Of course, assuming $\dfrac{PJ}{M} < 1$ and $J > -1.$